# How do I get a pig into a wagon/trailer?

Tags: farm-animals, pig

My dad wanted me to help out on his farm every once in a while, and one of my jobs is to get the 2 pot belly pigs into out trailer. How on earth do I get these fat pigs into the trailer?

Comment: WIthout some clarification this question might be out of scope.  If they are pet potbelly pigs you should be able to pick them and carry them into the trailer.  If it is difficult to get them into the trailer, it suggests it does not happen often, so why do you want to get pigs on a farm into a trailer? Images to that suggest a question that is not appropriate for a site about pets.

Comment: @JamesJenkins My dad had just bought them, and they are not very tame.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget that pigs are roughly as intelligent as dogs and as stubborn as mules. Coercing them is easier than forcing them.

You should call them to you, lure them with food like cheese and block their way backwards in case they change their mind.

What you **should avoid** is pushing them from behind, pulling them by the ears and causing them pain or panic.